# Uploading files on Elastic beanstalk using django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app and its migrated to the Elastic Beanstalk (AWS), But I cant see any media files on the server. I tried uploading my files using FileField and ImageField but the server doesnt render any of the images uploaded.

Comment: What is the error? django is not Beanstalk friend. You need some special stuff to make it work properly. Did you set the static path?